# how to convert a single json file to multiple json files for each image

Tags: json, python-3.x, machine-learning, deep-learning, dataset

convert a single json file to multiple json_files for ms_coco dataset. In ms_coco dataset we have single json files for each train2017, train2014, val2017, or val2014.

Datasets structure

datasets

```
ms_coco
   annotations
   images
   train2017_annotations
   val2017_annotations
```

[image]

when we open 'annotations' folder we get the following json files

[image]

The question is instead of using single json file (E.g., 'person_keypoints_train2017.json'), generating multiple json files for each image

Answer (score -1):

The following python script (generate_jsons.py) is to convert a single ms-coco json file to multiple json files for each image.

I used here ms_coco 2017 person_keypoints json file an example, but it can be modified to other files too

[image]

Finally, Run the python code

```
python generate_jsons.py
```

Finally, we will have

[image]

The python script 'python generate_jsons.py' can be found at https://github.com/teddylegessemunea/convert_a_json_to_multiple_json_files

Enjoy it !!!